# How do I use the enumerate function for CodeHS 8.4.13: Owls, Part 2?

Tags: python

This is what I'm supposed to do:

> This program is an extension of your previous ‘Owls’ program. You can
>   find your previous program here!
>
> In addition to just reporting how many words contained the word owl,
>   you should report the indices at which the words occurred!
>
> Here’s what an example run of your program might look like:
>
> ```
> Enter some text: Owls are so cool! I think snowy owls might be my
> favorite. Or maybe spotted owls.
> ```
>
> There were 3 words that contained
>   "owl". They occurred at indices: `[0, 7, 15]` As you can see from the
>   output, you’ll have to use another list to store the indices where you
>   found the words containing “owl”.
>
> The enumerate function might also come in handy!

This is my code right now:

```
text = input("Enter some text: ")
text.lower()
text.split()
print "There are " + str(text.count("owl")) + " words that contained \"owl\"."
print "They occured at indices: for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

I have absolutely no idea how to use the `enumerate` function. The way that I am using the `enumerate` function right now is something that I got from some other website. When I try to run this code, the first thing that I get is this error:

```
Error: Line 5
ParseError: bad token on line 5
```

From this, I know that the way I am using `enumerate` is wrong. However, I do not know the right way to use it.

Comment: What links did you find when searching for examples of how to use `enumerate()`?

Comment: [link](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/enumerate.html)

Comment: Did you try any of the code listed in the link?

Comment: I said in the description that the way I am using `enumerate` right now is from a website. This is that website.

Comment: Ok, what do you make of the error that you posted? (You're already doing a lot better at stackoverflow that others that don't post their errors!)

Comment: What do you mean by what I make of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this line here:

```
print "They occured at indices: for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

You have not ended the string with `"` so Python keeps reading more and more, assuming there is still more to this string, until it reaches the end of your file.  You don't want this, as the part: `for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):` is a command you want Python to do, it is not itself a string you want Python to print.  So first we close your string:

```
print "They occured at indices: "
for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):
    print(c, value)
```

This should get rid of your error, but will print the wrong answers.  You have another issue in the line: `text.split()` where you do not understand just how `split()` works.  I'll leave researching that part up to you.

Comment: By the way, I am using `split()` right. It worked like that.

Comment: Does your `text` actually change after you use `text.split()`? I am of the impression that it does not, but I might be confused with version differences as I am using Python 3 to your Python 2

Answer (score 0):

```
text = input("Enter some text: ")
text.lower()
text.split()
print "There are " + str(text.count("owl")) + " words that contained \"owl\"."
print "They occured at indices: for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):"
print "They occured at indices: "
for c, value in enumerate(text, 1):
print(c, value)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).